# Web Developer 2010 Express project solution will not upgrade to Express For Web 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have website I developed years ago using Web Developer 2010 Express.  Since then, I have always saved the solution (project folder) and installed on new computers.  The computer that had 2010 WDE installed has since been deemed unusable.  I haven't been able to find a download for it.  Microsoft no longer provides it. This was a personal project, so backing up the software didn't seem important at the time. I figured I'd be able to download in the future when needed. Sadly, I cannot find a download.

So I tried to download Express For Web 2015 and open the project. However, I get an error saying the project isn't compatible and The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information.

And tells me to go to this website for more information. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325

The one time this link come up, mentioned about creating a new empty 2015 project and copying some stuff over.  Unfortunately, I can no longer get the site to come up.  Not even sure if that would be the right solution.  I would prefer not to re-write the entire application.

I came close in the Microsoft visual studio site at downloading it. I saw a link about downloading older versions but said that I needed a subscription to download.  Unfortunately, the cheapest I found was $499.  No thanks, not when it was free to download, install and use. I'll pay maybe $10 bucks now, but not $499.

This is a solution using ASPX views and MVC version 4. C# code.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For those that come across this and have the same issue. I changed my project type guids from

```
 <ProjectTypeGuids>{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};{34‌​9c5851-65df-11da-938‌​4-00065b846f21};{fae‌​04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b‌​-00c04f79efbc}</Proj‌​ectTypeGuids>
```

to

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{34‌​9c5851-65df-11da-938‌​4-00065b846f21};{fae‌​04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b‌​-00c04f79efbc}</Proj‌​ectTypeGuids>
```

Comment: can you add some explanation of what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Log into https://my.visualstudio.com
2. Select the Downloads tab
3. Search for "Visual Studio 2010 VWD Express"
4. Click on Download button to download file
5. Click on Get Key link for the registration key